# Behat Scenario Registration - not finding text

Tags: php, symfony, selenium, bdd, behat

I have a very strange behaviour at a very basic scenario i've written. When not running the scenario with "@javascript" tag and selenium server, behat always fails and tells me that the specified text could not be found. But when I put @javascript, start selenium server and run the scenario again, everything passes. The site it is testing is just a basic registration site that gets submitted via post, and when registration is completed, the user gets redirected to "/register/success", where the message is displayed on the screen. When I do not run with selenium, the user does not even get saved in the database and the test fails due to missing text.:

```
@javascript // <-- only passing when adding this and starting selenium
Scenario: Fill in correct fields and register user
Given I am on "/register"
When I fill in the following:
  | Username        | usernotreserved         |
  | Email           | test@web.com            |
  | Password        | test1234!               |
  | Repeat password | test1234!               |
And I press "Register"
Then I should see "The user has been created successfully"
```

I've also tried the scenario manually by filling out the form and the user gets registered and saved in the database correctly.

Running Behat v3 on PHP7.

Running behat with -vvv gives the following output:

[image: behat -vvv output]

The huge error is not being shown when running with "javascript".

Behat.yml file:

```
extensions:
 Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
 Behat\MinkExtension:
  base_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
  goutte: ~
  selenium2: ~
  sessions:
    default:
      symfony2: ~
```

I think the best option would be to always use "@javascript", because then I don't need to worry about finished page loads..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Then print last response
```

or

```
Then print current URL
```

(put it after And I press "Register")

also

run behat with -vvv flag.

Maybe the url is pointing to wrongly configured env like app_test.php in normal behat scenario, or you have some js that prevents from normal page processing?

Comment: the url is correct, I've added a screenshot of the output of "-vvv" to my initial question

Comment: ok, so you have error - now you must fix it. Interesting  it's not appearing on your manual test. Use Then print last response to see full error page.

Comment: print last response output huge symfony exception page, I think this will return the same as I posted above. I just don't understand why this only appears when not using @javascript tag...

Comment: what is behat.yml for this?

Comment: maybe you have different error reporting in php.ini for cli (console). Do you use some salt option in security.yml ?

Comment: yes, for fosuserbundle: "encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt". But why should this be a problem, if it is working all fine when trying manually or per js, its very confusing .. I thought of maybe php7 problems.

Comment: "use of salt option to password_hash is deprecated" is the problem and deprecation errors are probably not displayed in your page - what is error_reporting in your php.ini?

Comment: nothing specified for error_level, but I will google for the deprecation error and bcrypt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99358/discussion-between-greg606-and-user3746259).

Comment: To anyone else: The error lays in php7 / Symfony registration as I can say for now. Will have a look at it tomorrow again.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the fact that you are not giving any time for the page to load after you have hit the button. Try adding a waiting time such as:

Given I wait "3000" seconds // 3 seconds

I believe you have to write the function iwaitseconds(n){} for that to work.

Example:

```
public function iWaitSeconds($seconds) { 
    $this->getSession()->wait($seconds); 
}
```

You can also use the following function if you believe there is ajax involved.

```
public function iWaitForAjaxToFinish() {
    $this->getSession()->wait(5000, '(typeof(jQuery)=="undefined" || (0 === jQuery.active && 0 === jQuery(\':animated\').length))');
  }
```

And this is how you call them in your scenario:

```
Given I wait for AJAX to finish
Given I wait "3000" seconds
```

Comment: is there no behat "method" that waits until the request is finished? How does this function need to look like? Thanks

Comment: I think waiting makes only sense in js scenario which in this case works ok.

Comment: @user3746259, please see my answer above. I've updated my answer with examples how to write the functions. If it helps please can you vote my answer.